# Why does Python think this is a tuple?

Tags: python

```
def my_function(fname):
    print(fname + " Refsnes")

my_function("Emil")
my_function("Tobias")
my_function("Linus")

def my_greeting(*fname):
    print(fname + " Smith")

my_greeting("Don")
```

The first part runs fine the second part crashes. Here are the results.

```
Emil Refsnes
Tobias Refsnes
Linus Refsnes

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Data/Python/turtleFun/kikiFunction.py", line 19, in <module>
    my_greeting("Don")
  File "C:/Data/Python/turtleFun/kikiFunction.py", line 17, in my_greeting
    print(fname + " Smith")
 TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

I haven't created a tuple, I'm not trying to concatenate. The structures are the same but one runs and the other crashes. Why does Python 3.8.3 think I have a tuple? How do I fix? Tuples would be

```
myTuple = ("Don", "Fred", "George", "Paul", "John", "Ringo")
```

Comment: *"I'm not trying to concatenate"* - you are, that's what `+` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

The `*` next to `*fname` makes `fname` a tuple, always.

## Understanding what's going on

Let's see what a function with `*fname` as a parameter really does.

```
>>> def func(*fnames):
...     print(fnames)
...     print(type(fnames))
>>> func('str 1', 'str 2')
('str 1', 'str 2')
<class 'tuple'>
```

Look at that! Even though it *seems* like `func` takes just 1 parameter (`*fnames`) we don't get an error even though when we call it with 2 parameters (`'str 1'` and `'str 2'`). That's because the `*` in `*fnames` lets any number of parameters (including 0!) to be passed to `func`, and **all of those parameters get passed in as 1 `tuple`**.

This is why, *even when you pass just 1 argument to the function*, `fnames` still takes on the type of `tuple`. In your example:

```py
def my_greeting(*fname):
    print(fname)  # let's not concatenate for now

my_greeting('Don')  # prints a tuple: ('Don',)
```

## Why doesn't Python only use tuples when `*fnames` is given 2+ args?

Python always uses tuples for `*`-type arguments so that our code can always expect a certain type. Otherwise, `my_greeting('Don')` would set `fnames` to a `str`, while `my_greeting('Don', 'Don2')` would set `fnames` to a `tuple` of `str`.

I hope this helps you learn!

Comment: Also: `*fnames` doesn't just allow for 1 or more arguments, it allows for *zero* arguments. `my_greeting()` is legal, and having an empty tuple lets you distinguish that from any other possible single argument.

Comment: Yep! Good point, adding that now.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! The video series I'm learning from didn't mention that the *fnames would be treated as a tuple when you passed an argument of ("Don") to it, or that you could just pass (Don) and it would be treated as  a string. I've learned a LOT about python from this free online video class, but it's left me with a LOT of unanswered questions. I will add this info to my notes.